# Airbyte Missing Columns in tables

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, open-source, aws-datasync, airbyte

I am considering Airbyte as a replacement for singer-io because of its user-friendly UI and code reduction features.
However, facing an issue where Airbyte is unable to detect certain columns in our source (Atlas hosted on AWS), which is a significant concern for me.

For instance,
Consider a table users with columns `user_id`, `name`, `location`, `phone_num`.
While the sync is performed, column `location` is missed, while it is present in mongo db.
In Airbyte UI also column `location` is not being shown.
I tried to figure out this issue via Octavia CLI, but could not find any way that columns can be defined.
Just wanted to mention that this column has ~70% nan values.
But going with the fact that even for 30% of data the column should not be missed.

I tried to re-sync data but no results.
I tried to install Octavia CLI to try to define columns for the table, but no such option was available.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with custom datatypes in Airbyte before where fields are silently left out of the schema discovery process.

Try sticking to the intrinsic types.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).